# ggdendrogram : adding colored rectangles for each cluster

Tags: r, dendextend, ggdendro

I am not able to add colored rectangles around the chosen clusters.

```
   library(lattice)
   library(permute)
   library(vegan)
   library("ggplot2")
   library("ggdendro")
   library("dendextend")
   data(dune)
   d <- vegdist(dune)
   csin <- hclust(d, method = "aver")
   ggdendrogram(csin)
   rect.dendrogram(csin, 3, border = 1:3)
```

I get this answer:
"Error in rect.dendrogram(csin, 3, border = 1:3) :
x is not a dendrogram object."
Although csin is the dendrogram object. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: You're mixing two packages here. The ggdendeo package is superseded by the dendextend package. Also, the rect.dendrogram function is for base R plots. It doesn't support ggplot2.

Comment: Also, csin is not a dendrogram, it's an hclust object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments:

1. csin is hclust and not a dendrogram (use as.dendrogram to make it into a dendrogram)
2. rect.dendrogram works with base R plots, not ggplot2.

Here is a simple example of making your rect.dendrogram work:

```
library("dendextend")
d <- dist(iris[,-5])
csin <- as.dendrogram(hclust(d, method = "aver"))
plot(csin)
rect.dendrogram(csin, 3, border = 1:3)
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Since the question was specifically about `ggdendro` package, any thoughts on drawing cluster rectangles in ggplot?

Comment: Sorry but it is not implemented. If someone wants to work on it I'd be happy to add it to dendextend